# Show thumbnail image and delete image in custom module admin form

Tags: magento-1.9, adminform, admin-panel, varien-file-uploader

I'm trying to display thumbnail image in my custom admin module edit form like this
[image]
Right now I'm using this `addfield`.

```
 $fieldset->addField('main_image', 'image', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('ram')->__('Image'),
        'required'  => false,
        'name'      => 'main_image',
    ));
```

I looked at `lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element/Image.php` and found this code which uses images url there.

```
public function getElementHtml()
    {
        $html = '';

        if ((string)$this->getValue()) {
            $url = $this->_getUrl();

            if( !preg_match("/^http\:\/\/|https\:\/\//", $url) ) {
                $url = Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . $url;
            }
```

But I'm not storing images in media folder for this module. I'm uploading images from the controller in `ram_images` folder.

```
 $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS .'ram_images' ;
   $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['main_image']['name'] );
```

Also, i could not change URL from `Image.php` file as it will affect other system modules. is there any workaround here. Please suggest a solution.

And I also want to delete image using checkbox provided below upload button.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the code in your controller file

```
public function saveAction() 
{
    ...

    if (!empty( $_FILES['main_image']['name'] )) 
    {
        $data['main_image'] =  $_FILES['main_image']['name'] ;
    } 
    else 
    {
        if (isset($data['main_image']['delete']) && $data['main_image']['delete'] == 1) 
        {
            if ($data['main_image']['value'] != '')
                $this->removeFile($data['main_image']['value']);
            $data['main_image'] = '';
        }
        else 
        {
            unset($data['main_image']);
        }
    }

    ...
}
public function removeFile($file) 
{
        $_helper = Mage::helper('ram');
        $file = $_helper->updateDirSepereator($file);
        $directory = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS .'ram_images' ;
        $io = new Varien_Io_File();
        $result = $io->rmdir($directory, true);
}
```

Create below function in Helper Class

```
 public function updateDirSepereator($path) 
    {
        return str_replace('\\', DS, $path);
    }
```

Comment: i will try this, i hope it works

Answer (score 7):

Add  `'enctype'’ ⇒ 'multipart/form-data'` That should help to get something in  `$_FILES`

in /app/code/local/Chilly/ModName/Block/Adminhtml/ModName/Edit/Form.php

You should have something looking like this:

```
$form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(

         'id' => 'edit_form',

        'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' =>    $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),

        'method' => 'post',

        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'

    )

);
```

Then in /app/code/local/Chilly/ModName/Block/Adminhtml/ModName/Edit/Tab/Form.php

```
$fieldset->addField('main_image', 'image', array(
    'label'     => Mage::helper('ram')->__('Image'),
    'required'  => false,
    'name'      => 'main_image',
));
```

Then in /app/code/local/Chilly/ModName/controllers/Adminhtml/ModuleNameController.php  in `saveAction()`

```
        if(isset($_FILES['main_images']['name'])) {
          try {
            $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('main_images');
            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png')); // or pdf or anything
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
            $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
            $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS. 'ram_images'.DS ;
            $destFile = $path.$_FILES['main-images']['name'];
            $filename = $uploader->getNewFileName($destFile);
            $uploader->save($path, $filename);
            $data[main_images] = 'ram_images'. $filename;
          }catch(Exception $e) { }
       }
```

Your's edit form will be display image like as..

[image]

Comment: I have already uploaded image. i just want it to display as a thumbnail on edit form.

Comment: Above code will be display image in your edit form.

Comment: Yeah, probably. But i'm using `$path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS .'ram_images';` this path to upload images.

Answer (score 4):

I think i got a simple solution here to display thumbnail image.

```
if(isset($_FILES['main_images']['name'])) {
          try {
            $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('main_images');
            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
            $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
            $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . / ;
            $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['main_images']['name']);
            $data[main_images] ='ram_images'. $_FILES['main_images']['name'];
          }catch(Exception $e) { }
       }
```

just saved folder name too in the table and it worked.

To delete image just added following code to module controllers `saveAction()` function.

```
if (!empty( $_FILES['main_image']['name'] )) 
 {
    $data['main_image'] =  $_FILES['main_image']['name'] ;
 } 
 else 
 {
     if (isset($data['main_image']['delete']) && $data['main_image']['delete'] == 1) 
     {
         $data['main_image']='';
     }
     else 
     { 
         unset($data['main_iamge']);
      }
 }
```

It worked.

Comment: Hi @HungryDB, this worked for me as well, but partially. The images are being uploaded but the thumbnail doesn't show up on the form, only the browse button. Do I have to add a function to helper as well to make it work?

Comment: use field type `image`

Comment: Hi @HungryDB, I did, but it still only shows the button.